# Como transportar dados do R para o excel?

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Calculei uma série de dados no R e gostaria de saber qual comando devo usar para transportá-los para uma planilha do excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando a ser executado utilizando o package [xlsReadWrite](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xlsReadWrite/) deve ser:

```
library(xlsReadWrite)
write.xls(mydata, "c:/arquivo.xls")
```

Ou você pode usar um dos seguintes packages:

1. [WriteXLS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html)
2. [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/)

Comment: o pacote xlsReadWrite foi removido do CRAN. a resposta ao post original não deveria incluir o pacote.

Comment: Ainda assim existe o arquivo e está disponível para download. Assim sendo, é uma das algumas opções listadas na resposta. Cabe à quem perguntou escolher a que lhe convém.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(nomeObjeto,file="nomeObjeto.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

O pacote [WriteXLS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html) pode ser util. Depois de instalar o pacote, basta digitar o seguinte comando:

```
WriteXLS("m", "n.xls")
```

Onde `m` é a base de dados que estás trabalhando no Excel e `n` o nome do artigo que quer exportar em xls.

Com esse pacote, dá pra editar algumas caracteristicas do arquivo exportado, como os headers e largura das colunas...

Comment: Oi, user7779, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, use um corretor ortográfico no seu browser, isso facilita pra todo mundo, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo usando Excel eu prefiro trabalhar com arquivos CSV (texto sempre!), que com a formatação adequada, abrem no Excel sem problemas.
Para criar os arquivos CSV eu gosto de usar o `write.table`.

Para que os arquivos sejam abertos no Excel em Português corretamente eu uso:

```
write.table(df, file='arquivo.csv', sep=';', dec=',', row.names=FALSE)
```

Para que os arquivos sejam abertos no Excel em Inglês corretamente eu uso:

```
write.table(df, file='arquivo.csv', sep=',', dec='.', row.names=FALSE)
```

Você pode abrir diretamente o arquivo no Excel clicando sobre o ícone do arquivo (pelo menos no Windows).
Com a vantagem de que o arquivo é portável para qualquer outra programa e SO.

Comment: Da para usar os aliases deles: `write.csv()` para o formato americano e `write.csv2()` para o formato brasileiro

Comment: Eu prefiro deixar os comandos explícitos, se não isso fica que nem código PHP onde você precisa decorar uma centena de funções com nomes parecido.