# Exportar dados do R para o Excel formatados

Tags: r, microsoft-excel, data.frame, tabela-html

Suponha um `data.frame` como este:

```
tabela <- structure(list(vendedor = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "factor"), Total = c(3300, 440, 1020, 200)), .Names = c("vendedor", 
"Total"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), drop = TRUE)
```

Como exportá-la em Excel, colocando detalhes como título, subtítulo, formatação de tamanhos e fontes dos textos e números? [Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10684/como-transportar-dados-do-r-para-o-excel?rq=1) há sugestões de pacotes para salvar em Excel, entretanto não se trata de como formatar os dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o pacote WriteXLS, dá pra fazer algumas coisas.

A sintaxe é essa:

```
WriteXLS(x, ExcelFileName = "R.xls", SheetNames = NULL, perl = "perl",
verbose = FALSE, Encoding = c("UTF-8", "latin1"),
row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,
AdjWidth = FALSE, AutoFilter = FALSE, BoldHeaderRow = FALSE,
FreezeRow = 0, FreezeCol = 0,
envir = parent.frame())
```

- Se `AdjWidth = TRUE`, ajusta a largura de cada coluna pelo valor mais comprido.
- Se `AutoFilter = TRUE`, a planilha xlx ja sai com autofiltro
- Se `BoldHeaderRow = TRUE`, nome de cada coluna em negrito

Os comandos `FreeRow` e `Freezecol` indicam quais colunas devem sair congeladas.